# discord.py add specific time to countdown in def function

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm using `discord.py` to write a bot. I'm trying to write a function that can mute a specified person for a specified time. For example, one could mute a person for 10 minutes, and once a 10-minute countdown timer was over, the person would be unmuted again.

Here's what I have so far:

```
@bot.command(aliases=["m", "M", "Mute"])
async def mute(ctx ,*,member: discord.Member):
    command_name = "mute"
    author = ctx.author

    await member.edit(mute=True)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} muted for {time} minutes")
    await member.edit(mute=False)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has unmuted")
```

Comment: You can use `tasks.loop` for that task(No pun intended). You can make like two functions, namely `mute` and 'unmute`.

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/

Comment: You can probably use `await asyncio.sleep(600)` after the mute and before the unmute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is using the asyncio module. You could replace your current code:

```
@bot.command(aliases=["m", "M", "Mute"])
async def mute(ctx ,*,member: discord.Member):
    command_name = "mute"
    author = ctx.author

    await member.edit(mute=True)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} muted for {time} minutes")
    await member.edit(mute=False)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has unmuted")
```

to this:

```
import asyncio

@bot.command(aliases=["m", "M", "Mute"])
async def mute(ctx, time, *, member: discord.Member):
    command_name = "mute"
    author = ctx.author

    await member.edit(mute=True)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} muted for {time} minutes")

    # Wait time before the user gets un-muted   
    await asyncio.sleep(time)

    await member.edit(mute=False)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has unmuted")
```

And you would use the command in discord like: `[prefix]mute {time} {member}`

--WARNING--

If you restart your bot between the time that the user is muted, the muted member will not be un-muted by the bot. You could save the time to a database that refreshes every second to fix this problem.